# Understanding the operator notation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I know if I have say $v_t + a v_x = 0$ I can write it as $Lv = 0$ where

$$ L = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + a\frac{ \partial }{\partial x} \; \; \; \; \; and \; \; \; \; v=v(x,t)$$

Now, Given a difference scheme, say

$$ u_k^{n+1} = u_{k}^{n-1} - \frac{a \Delta t}{\Delta x}( u_{k+1}^n - u_{k-1}^n ) $$

In my books, I am given that a scheme is consistent if $L_k^n v_k^n - G_k^n \to 0 $ and $\Delta t, \Delta x \to 0$.

Im trying to understand the notation of the sequence. If I rewritte the scheme I have

$$ \frac{u_k^{n+1} - u_k^{n-1} }{\Delta t } + a \frac{ u_{k+1}^n - u_{k-1}^n }{\Delta x} = 0 $$

Which looks as our pde. I am having hard time trying to visualize what is $L_k^n$, $v_k^n$ and $G_k^n$ in this scheme. Can someone point me in the right direction? best regards

Comment: A scheme is consistent if the approximate solution converges to the true solution as $\Delta t, \Delta x \to 0$. From this, I would hazard a guess that $L_{k}^{n} v_{k}^{n}$ represents your _numerical approximation_ to the solution at time $n$ and position $k$ and that $G_{n}^{k}$ represents the _actual_ solution to the PDE at time $n$ and position $k$. However, this is just a guess as the book you are using might already have defined what $G$ represents. Can you tell us more about what $G$ is?

Comment: I just saw in the book it says: $G_n^k$  denotes whatever approximation has been made of the source term

Comment: where $Lv = F$. I believe $G_k^n$ is zero in my example but in general it approximateds $F$, correct ?

Comment: Ok, well that seems to be equivalent to my statement above. Using the definition you just gave for $G$, for the PDE above $$v_{t} + av_{x} = 0$$ we see that, yes, $G \equiv 0$.